# how to format large numbers using spaces instead fo comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using `django.contrib.humanize` **intcomma** tag to format large numbers like this **$18,162,711,641**

but what I want spaces instead of comma, like this **$18 162 711 641**

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: You probably have to implement your own template filter with [same implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#L60) but [instead with space](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#L74)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m)

This is what works for me. I had to put this in `app_name/templatetags` directory and load it in template using `{% load intspace %}`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def intspace(value):
    import re

    orig = str(value)

    new = re.sub(r"^(-?\d+)(\d{3})", r"\g<1> \g<2>", orig)
    if orig == new:
        return new
    else:
        return intspace(new)
```

inside template you can use it like
`{{ 18162711641|intspace }}`